# Is it possible to configure WSUS to download and put updates for a specific software type in a specific location?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, wsus, windows-update

Our network uses WSUS to download and install approved updates to most of our workstations. We also have SharePoint servers that we manually update via cumulative updates (CUs) once per month. The current process requires us going to Microsoft's SharePoint guru, Stefan Gossner's, blog to view any known issues with the latest CU, and then download and install it on the servers.

My question is: Is it possible to configure WSUS to automatically download the latest CU (latest right now is KB 4484187) into a specific shared folder, by itself, so that when it's time to update, we can simply research known issues and then install without having to wait for the download? If this is possible, it would save us approximately 20-30 minutes every time we need to update. Given it takes around 4-6 hours to update our servers already, any time saved would be of great benefit.

I know the basics of WSUS, but I can't seem to find anything on how to configure it for this specific task.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way directly, but I have found a way, with disclaimer that I found it but not used it.

First, of course, you have to have the WSUS configured to check for updates for that product.

Then you either have to approve the update so that it is downloaded or have the item in **Options > Update Files and Languages > Download update files to this server only when updates are approved** turned off (I *highly* recommend the first option here).

Next, locate the Update that you want to extract in the list of Updates. Right-click, then select File Information. The **File URI** is the folder location. It won't be as simple as a MSU file.

After that, use **How to use DISM to install a hotfix from within Windows** as laid out at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askcore/how-to-use-dism-to-install-a-hotfix-from-within-windows

Reference forum discussion that I found on the topic: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be032412-aed8-488a-bfb8-bcfeb928b91d/how-to-export-msu-patch-installers-from-wsus-content?forum=winserverwsus